# How to change support of multivariate integral to [0,1]^k using scipy.integrate.quad?

Tags: python, math, scipy, dimension, integral

The following k-dimension integral has dependent limits (a support dependent on `gamma`):

```
from  scipy.integrate import nquad
import numpy as np

def func(*args):
    gamma = args[-1]
    var = np.array(args[:-1])

    return (1-1/(1+gamma-np.sum(var)))*np.prod(((1+var)**-2))

def range_func(*args):
    gamma = args[-1]
    return (0, gamma-sum(args[:-1]))

gamma, k = 10, 2
print(nquad(func, [range_func]*k, args=(gamma,) ))
```

The limits are defined inside the function `range_func` above

```
return (0, gamma-sum(args[:-1]))
```

How can this support be changed to simply `[0,1]^k` such that `scipy.integrate.nquad` still works? That is, each integral sign runs from 0 to 1. Do I just change it to `return (0,1)`?

([source of code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602089/implementing-numerical-integration-using-scipy-integrate-nquad), which is just a toy example of what I plan to do)

Comment: What is the integral which you are trying to approximate? How many dimensions is it exactly? It would help others understand what's going on if you say exactly what is the problem you are trying to solve. Thanks for any info.

Comment: the link is the last line in the question. that's all I know about it. I just want to confirm of `(0,1) *k`, `(0,1)**k` or other properly reflects an integral support (definite limits) of `[0,1]`

Comment: Well, in the code you can change it to return (0, 1), but that's going to change the integral, right? because now the integrand has a singularity within the domain of integration. Maybe it's going to be OK, maybe not, anyway it's not just a matter of changing the limits of integration in the code. At this point I think it becomes more of a math question than a programming question. By the way, I think it's generally helpful to include a complete description in the problem statement instead of linking to part of it.

Comment: right, this code was the closest I could find to the real problem I'm actually trying to solve. I didn't realize how complex changing the support would be code-wise, but in terms of math i know my real problem *must* have this support: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65691228/multivariate-integral-using-scipy-integrate-nquad-invalid-syntax-error-on-lamb

Comment: Well, it's kind of distracting when the linked-to problem is actually not the one you need to solve ... Anyway I see now that you opened a separate item about the problem you are trying to solve. I'll go comment there.

Comment: Thanks, i've updated that question with more details on the multiple integral's `[0,1]**k` support. All I'm really asking is how to install this support into the `integrate.nquad` input arguments

Comment: I don't understand your code. Is it an integral like [this one](https://laustep.github.io/stlahblog/posts/integralPolyhedron.html)?