# Triple integration using Boost quadratures in C++

Tags: python, c++, boost, numerical-integration

I am trying to write a triple integration routine in C++ using the Boost Gauss-Kronrod quadrature for a function returning a complex result. **I am not set on the Boost library, if there is another library that fits my requirements better suggestions are welcome**. I am looking for an alternative to scipy since it doesn't support integrands returning complex values, meaning I have to integrate twice (complex and real part) and I am looking for a faster method.

Scipy.integrate provides a `tplquad` function which integrates f(x, y, z). The integration interval can even be specified as a lambda function, so integration over a spherical domain is possible. Scipy also has `nquad`, which can integrate over n dimensions.
So far I have failed to write something similar in C++, since the boost integration doesn't have an args parameter to allow me to pass additional arguments to a function. In Python with the quad 1D integration routine from scipy I could pass the current y,z values to the x integration.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51305099/11500265) has code that shows what I am thinking about doing in C++, using a 1D integration routine for 3D integration.

Comment: I don't think you need an `args` parameter for boost. Just use a lambda to consume any extra state you need.

Comment: If you use Python, check out [quadpy](https://github.com/nschloe/quadpy) (a project of mine). It supports complex-valued integrands, is fully vectorized.

Comment: @Nico Schlömer
I just finished implementing the integration in quadpy and I am very happy with the speed.